# How do I plan a users routing in chronological order?

Tags: android, google-maps

STILL DESPERATELY LOOKING FOR ANSWERS

I have integrated Google Map's dynamic geocoding in my android project(when the user types an address, it goes there and places a marker). My plan however is to let someone else plan the users schedule for the day.

For example, someones mother wants her son(the user) to do some errands for her. So she opens the app on her phone and types in the places she wants her son to go. The son get the places he needs to go in a chronological order, i.e, the vacuum cleaner store, the hardware depot and then the supermarket. First, the route to the vacuum cleaner store(from his current location) shows up. He goes there, an then presses "done". Then the route from his location to the hardware depot is shown,and so on and so forth.

Not necessary, but appreciated: He should be able to open a navigation drawer with all the errands in a list format, from the first errand to the last.

To summarize, how do I plan someones route in chronological order? I know I am asking for a lot, but if anyone could help me out, that would be great. I would literally sing your praises.

Thanks for reading this wall of text!

Answer (score 1):

It is just an idea, maybe you can try to use [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) under the [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction).

You can use this waypoints to calculate the routes through additional location.

Here is an example request using waypoints in Direction API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can supply one or more locations separated by the pipe character (|), in the form of an **address**, **latitude/longitude coordinates**, or a **place ID**.

Although this is in JavaScript, this is an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints) on how to use waypoints.

Comment: Good suggestion! I have upvoted but not accepted yet, as I am still open to answers.